# unresolved import "home". How do I fix this? The views file and the urls file are int the same "home" folder

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

[image]

> unresolved import "home".

How do I fix this? The views file and the urls file are int the same "home" folder.

[image]

Comment: You should not post images of your code. Please read the guidelines on asking questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added the images from link, but I suggest to add relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from . import views
```

because you are in the same directory